# How can i list all the ftp files by using ListView?

Tags: android, listview, ftp

Well, i searched many information, but i still didn't get it. How can i list all the ftp files by using ListView on android ?

is there any example, or simple coding to explanation how can i do it.

I know how to make a sample ListView

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
   TextView selection;
   String[] items;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      items=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
      selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
   }

   public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
      selection.setText("Planet - "+items[position]);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
}
```

And i have the coding that can show the files in the server on Eslipse.

```
public void ftpPrintFilesList(String dir_path)
{
    try {
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
        int length = ftpFiles.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
            boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();

            if (isFile) {
                Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
            }

        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But i have no idea how to put the file information into the ListView.
i am petty bad on coding, please help. Thank you.

### **UPDATE:**

After i rebuild the coding, its show an error, i copy my coding down there.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity have error implements OnClickListener {



String mString = "/";
private Context cntx = null;
TextView selection;
private ArrayList<String> fileNames;
MyFTPClient ftpclient = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileNames));
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
    cntx = this.getBaseContext();
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    View button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);

    ftpclient = new MyFTPClient();} 

    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button5:
    setContentView(R.layout.ftpfile);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run(){
    ftpclient.ftpPrintFilesList(mString);} }).start();
    break;
    }
        }
```

And this is the method that i used on the other java file:

```
public ArrayList<String> ftpPrintFilesList(String dir_path)
{
    ArrayList<String> validFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
        int length = ftpFiles.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
            boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();

            if (isFile) {
                validFileNames.add(name);
                Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
            }

        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return validFileNames;
}
```

This is my ListView page (xml) called ftpfile.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/selection"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FF0000"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
/>


<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
/>
```

And the LogCat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ftptest/com.example.ftptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Sorry, if this is too long, but i really need to solve the problem. Please help thank you.

Comment: Well once you have the files from the path, you could just create an array or ArrayList of the names of the files and return it to the activity where you could pass that array to the adapter (in place of the items String array).

Comment: is there any sample coding? i am very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Well you've done most of the coding. I've edited your code a bit

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private TextView selection;
    private ArrayList<String> fileNames;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fileNames = ftpPrintFilesList(pathOfFTPDirectory); 

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileNames));
        selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
        selection.setText("Planet - "+ fileNames.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> ftpPrintFilesList(String dir_path)
    {
        ArrayList<String> validFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
            int length = ftpFiles.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
                boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();

                if (isFile) {
                    validFileNames.add(name);
                    Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
                }

            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return validFileNames;
    } 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Change this in the xml for removing the error

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Comment: Well what about your directory path? Is that correct? Also, which library are you using which contains the FTPFilePath class? Or is it a user defined class?

Comment: directory path is "/".

Comment: One question though - Is it really you who is writing the code?? If you have no idea what you're doing then who is writing all this code?

Comment: ftp part is find on internet.. sorry

Comment: In that case, you'll just have to study the code which you are referring to.